# Problema tinymce en laravel 9 al mostrar datos en pantalla

Tags: php, html, laravel, tinymce, laragon

Con las muy buenas a todos, muestro mi Código en laravel 9, con Tinymce para recoger los datos desde el usuario a través de POST. Estoy trabajando en laragon 6.

Html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"><script src="https://cdn.tiny.cloud/1/nftneibcgkgxik91ybc1kpaau1jmp6ljbpifsv1cnssjgq9h/tinymce/5/tinymce.min.js" referrerpolicy="origin"></script>
@include('tiny')
```

tiny.blade.php agregado a html a través de @include

```
<script>
tinymce.init({
selector: "textarea", // Replace this CSS selector to match the placeholder element for TinyMCE
height: 400,
plugins: 'code table lists emoticons image media link',
toolbar1: 'undo redo | formatselect| bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright | indent outdent | bullist numlist | code | table emoticons',
toolbar2: 'image media | link unlink',
image_advtab: true ,
remove_linebreaks : false
});
</script>
```

Vista Nuevo Artículo

```
@extends('layout.layoutadmin')
@section('titulo','Nuevo Articulo')
@section('contenido')
<form action="narticulo" method="POST">
@csrf
<div class="row">
...
<div class="mt-2">
<textarea name="contenido">{{ old('contenido') }}</textarea>
     @error('contenido')
         <div class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</div>
     @enderror
</div>
```

A través de ese Form recojo toda la información para ingresar a la base de datos y con el controlador lo grabo en mysql.

Controlador AdminController

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Models\Blog;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
 
class AdministracionController extends Controller{
public function graboarticulo(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'contenido' => ['required']
    ]);

    $blog = new Blog;
    $blog->contenido = $request->input('contenido');
    $blog->save();

    return to_route('articulos');
}
```

El problema es cuando recojo los datos y los muestro en pantalla me aparece el texto completo que es ingresado desde tinymce.

Función que recoge la data desde la base

```
public function veopost($slug){
$post = Blog::where('slug',$slug)->get();
return view('front.veo', ['post'=> $post]);
}
```

La vista lo muestro con

```
<div>{{ $post[0]->contenido}}</div>
```

Y me aparece lo siguiente (Extracto)

```
<p style="margin: 0px 0px 15px; padding: 0px; text-align: justify; font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; background-color: #ffffff;">&aacute; &eacute; &iacute; &oacute; &uacute;</p> <p style="margin: 0px 0px 15px; padding: 0px; text-align: justify; font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; background-color: #ffffff;">Al contrario del pensamiento popular, el texto de Lorem Ipsum no es simplemente texto aleatorio.
```

[image: imagen de error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probaste usando la sintaxis de blade para no 'escapear' los strings?

En vez de `{{ $post[0]->contenido }}`

Podrias usar `{!! $post[0]->contenido !!}`

[Laravel docs (ingles)](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/blade#displaying-unescaped-data)

Comment: Muchas Gracias por la información, me fue de muchísima ayuda y logre solucionar el problema. solo un detalle es {!! $post[0]->contenido !!} con un solo corchete, al poner los dos este queda un corchete en pantalla. Buena suerte

Comment: Uh tenes razon! Actualizo la respuesta para que cuando otro usuario lo vea no se confunda 